# GPIO input using a banana?

Tags: gpio

I am programming a music player that will be controlled by a bunch of bananas for the main functions as play/pause/etc.

How do I get a GPIO input of banana (in a way that it registers an input when I touch it)?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://www.instructables.com/id/Bananaphone-A-Touch-Capacitance-Synth/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a [piezo sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_sensor).  Mine's still in the drawer awaiting some free time, so I don't have any experience yet, but the idea is they can both generate and respond to vibration or pressure.  You can get very inexpensive ones from any electronics supplier.

Piezos are used as pickups on acoustic instruments such as guitars (although an electric guitar pickup is not a piezo -- they generate an active EMF).  A banana is probably not much of an acoustic instrument, but if you can wrap or coat the piezo in something and put it inside the banana, something might be made to happen.  I think a simple touch would be too subtle, though.

Comment: Good idea. Electricity alone won't do the trick?

Comment: I mean something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muzVxcOZFGM&feature=iv&src_vid=i1SyIXeFUB0&annotation_id=annotation_281958). Any idea how they pulled it off?

Comment: That's active EMF, or magic.  The GPIOs can be used to generate radio frequencies, which is how a [theramin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin) works; if you've ever seen one of those played it looks like that banana control.   You've almost certainly heard one, it's a very weird warbling used in old sci-fi, etc.   I did not listen to that video, I just watched the first 30 seconds, but the bananas there *may* be a hoax/gimmick (i.e. it's really just wires).  But I am relatively science ignorant at this point.